# wordpress error

Tags: wordpress

i completed my client site in wordpress,then i uploaded this site into client server(FTP) but site is not going to open 
this error is occur
"
Warning: fopen(piecemakerXML.xml) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in F:\inetpub\vhosts\kni.com.my\httpdocs\wp-content\themes\twentyten\header.php on line 133
can't open file"

Comment: This is impossible to answer well without any background. What is piecemakerXML.xml and is it present where it needs to be?

Comment: piecemakerXML.xml is a file which contains slider images in short slider in home page runs through this xml file

Answer (score 2):

It's a file system permissions problem. WordPress does not have permission to access that file or the folder it's in. You'll have to change that. Most FTP programs have a CHMOD command built in, or you can shell in to the server, or use the hosting control panel.

Answer (score 2):

Check the permissions of the file to ensure it is at least `readable` by the owner. And if you also want to write to it, it should be `writable`

Check out the page on Wordpress about file permissions. It has a pretty good list of example permissions
http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Also Check out wikipedia

And to Change file permissions, do what @Dan said in his answer.